# php -S randomly not working: localhost refused to connect

Tags: php, ubuntu, wsl-2

I am using WSL2 with ubuntu 20.04 with php 7.4.3 installed on it.
Sometimes, php -S (for example php -S localhost:9000 -t public) doesnt work, nor does php artisan serve.

EDIT: When trying to access the address localhost:9000 from the browser, i get:
"localhost refused to connect"
terminating WSL distro has never solved the issue. From the terminal i get the normal:
PHP 7.4.3 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:9000) started

Comment: Start by explaining what you mean by "doesnt work". Also please share any errors you're getting.

Comment: as per the title: i get the message localhost refused to connect ("ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED") in the browser when trying to access locaIhost:9000. have no idea how to process to give better insight into this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

This seems to be a [common issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4636) on WSL2, and a fix is coming.
In the meantime,

- wsl --shutdown may solve the issue.
- if that is indeed the case, you can get the correct localhost address by using the command below.

`ip addr | grep -E "\binet.global" | sed -E "s/inet(.)/./\1/“`